# Java - using Map how to find matching Key when Values are stored a List of strings

Tags: java, dictionary

All,

I have a map with categories and subcategories as lists like this:

```
    Map<String,List<String>> cat = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    List<String> fruit = new ArrayList<String>();
    fruit.add("Apple");
    fruit.add("Pear");
    fruit.add("Banana");

    cat.put("Fruits", fruit);

    List<String> vegetable = new ArrayList<String>();
    vegetable.add("Carrot");
    vegetable.add("Leak");
    vegetable.add("Parsnip");

    cat.put("Vegetables", vegetable);
```

I want to find if "Carrot" is in the map and to which key ("Fruit') it matches, however:

```
    if (cat.containsValue("Carrot")) {System.out.println("Cat contains Leak");}
```

gives False as outcome. How can I match "Carrot" and get back the key value "Vegetable"

Thx.

Comment: This is not the right way to check for values in map.

Comment: You'll have to iterate over every key in the map and check each list to see if it contains carrot... You can use _List.contains()_ to search each list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the *inversed* map:

```
Map<String, String> fruitCategoryMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Entry<String, List<String>> catEntry : cat.entrySet()) {
    for(String fruit : catEntry.getValue()) {
        fruitCategoryMap.put(fruit, catEntry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
String category = fruitCategoryMap.get("Banana"); // "Fruit"
```

Comment: Thx Vakh. Altouhg I am a novice at Java amd don't fully get this, it does gie desired result.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can read more about ``Map``: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html Please vote me up if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate thought all the keys and check in the value if found then break the loop.

```
for (String key : cat.keySet()) {
    if (cat.get(key).contains("Carrot")) {
        System.out.println(key + " contains Carrot");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the value in the entire map:

```
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : cat.entrySet()) {
    for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
        if (s.equals("Carrot"))
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Juvanis, compact code but does exactly what I want. Thx again.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : cat.entrySet()) {
        String names[] = entry.getValue().toArray(new String[entry.getValue().size()]);
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i].equals("Carrot")) {
                System.out.println("found"+names[i]);
                break;
            } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thx Hari. This works, it does confirm "Carrot" to be part of map. However, as in the top two examples the key to which "Carrot"  belongs is found as well, which I actually wanted. In that respect my `system.out.println` was to short an example.